# ScaleTransform applied to elements in stackpanel causes "white" space

Tags: silverlight, transform, render, scale, stackpanel

When I add UserControls that have a ScaleTransform applied to them to a StackPanel, I see that there is extra space in between the controls as though the transform was not applied.  From what I understand, a transform doesn't actual change the width/height of a control, but rather changes the render width/height.  If this is the case, how can I make the controls appear without the extra space?

Here's an example.  The first row represents what my controls look like without a transform applied.  The second row is what they look like with a ScaleTransform {ScaleX = .75, ScaleY = .75}.  I want the elements to bump up to each other like the first row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [LayoutTransformer](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%201&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#LayoutTransformer) class in the Silverlight toolkit.